# How to load and parse the contents of different url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load a url and parse its contents (say all anchor tags) inside a chrome extension using jquery .How can I do it?P.S. I am new to this so bare me if this question doesn't meet the criteria of S.O.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As is, it is indeed not a good question. Take time to read some introduction to SO: the [tour] and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. After that, you can get back and edit your question to make it better. Primarily, you need to show that you've spent some effort solving this yourself. And narrow the question down: it's a very broad one, but maybe you know how to do parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Phj9m/265/)

```
var datahtml = $("html").html();
 
$(datahtml).find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

What it does:

> var datahtml = $("html").html(); //gets the html
>
> $(datahtml).find('a').each(function() //looks for any a tags
>
> console.log($(this).attr('href')); //prints them out!